# wordpress plug-in development for dynamic url

Tags: wordpress, custom-url

I'm new to wordpress plug-in development.

I want to create one plug in. the functionality of plug-in is

# it will catch url like, www.example.com/custom_post_type/param1/parm2/parm3

param1,param2,param3 are parameters passed to custom_post_type.

# i need to catch these parameters and want to communicate to database accordingly i want to show page content.

i don't know whether i should use custom_post_type.(because i'll use self made tables to check for parameters)

please suggest me.

Comment: Can you add code that illustrates what you have, an example of where you want to go, and any details on the problems you're having achieving that?

Comment: i created custom post type
function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'rent',
            array(
                    'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'rent' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'rent' )
                    ),
            'public' => true,
            'menu_position' => 2,
            'rewrite' => true,
            //'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail')
            )
    );
}

i create one post by name car,
 it will give Permalink: http://localhost.wordpress.com/rent/car/ 

I wann /car/ parameter to be dynamic,

Comment: If i use custom post type, can i query database with self defined tables..?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the Wordpress Rewrite API. You can get more information about this at the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API)
Tutsplus has an great article about using the Rewrite API: [The Rewrite API: The Basics](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-rewrite-api-the-basics--wp-25474)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to validate if you can achieve efficiently what you want to do with Custom Post Type.  You do not give enough details to be able to tell you if it would be better, in this particular case, to use CPT or build custom tables.  That said, most of the time, you can use both: CPT mixed with custom tables.

As for your URL question, you need to play with the: [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).  This will enable you to manage the URLs the way you want.

Unfortunately, the Codex may be hard to understand.  Fortunately, you can check this great resource where Carl Alexander explains exactly how it works: [WordPress for the Adventurous : Rewrite API](http://carlalexander.ca/wordpress-adventurous-rewrite-api/).

Another possibility is to breakdown the URL by using the variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. That said, I would avoid this option if possible.  Using the rewrite API is the proper way to go.